# Ant Nested Loop

Tags: ant, copy, ant-contrib

I have two txt files: File1.txt – contains list of src dir; and File2.txt – contains list of dest dir. I need to do the copy using a loop from src dir to dest dir.

File1.txt (SVN dire structure)

```
abcBIN
abcBIN/fdPro
...so on
```

File2.txt (LINUX structure)

```
apps/xxx/yyy/bin/abc
apps/xxx/yyy/bin/abc/fdpro
...so on
```

I need to copy the abcBIN files dir to apps/xxx/yyy/bin/abc and so on. One to one mapping.

```
<project xmlns:ac="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib">

<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"> 
   <classpath>
      <pathelement location="path-to-ant-contrib.jar"/>
   </classpath>
</taskdef>

<loadfile property="file1" srcfile="File1.txt"/> 
<loadfile property="file2" srcfile="File2.txt"/>

<ac:for param="i" list="${file1}">
    <ac:for param="j" list="${file2}"> 
        <sequential>
           <echo>@{i}@{j}</echo>
           <echo>copying....</echo>

           <property name="src.dir" value="/home/name/svn_repo/dir" />
           <property name="dest.dir" value="/home/name/mapp" /> 
           <copy todir="${dest.dir}/@{j}">
              <fileset dir="${src.dir}/@{i}"> 
              </fileset>
           </copy>     
        </sequential>
     </ac:for>
</ac:for>

</project>
```

It is not working though.

I am getting an error:

```
ac:for doesn't support the nested "for" element
```

I can’t use UNIX shell or Perl. It has to be done in Ant.

Please let me know if you have any better idea about the nested loop in Ant.

Comment: I need to copy (file.txt dir to file2.txt dir) e.g abcBIN files dir to apps/xxx/yyy/bin/abc and so on. One to one mapping.

Comment: If you really want to do that, you need to put the second `<for>` inside `<sequential>`, and also, you need to put the `<echo>.....</copy>` part inside a `<sequential>` inside the second `<for>`.

Comment: coolcfan, if i use the logic you mentioned. It wont work for one to one mapping. e.g. one line from src then one line from dest dir

Comment: @ShwetaChandrakar You could post your solution so that others could benefit from it.

Comment: @ShwetaChandrakar  I need to know this solution .. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@PulakAgrawal: I combined two text files into one using colon as a line separator and the magic began :)

e.g. src path:dest path

```
     <loadfile property="allfiles" srcFile="mapping"/>

      <ac:for list="${allfiles}" param="line" delimiter="${line.separator}">

     <ac:sequential>

            <ac:propertyregex property="from" input="@{line}" regexp="(.*):(.*)" select="\1" override="true"/>

            <ac:propertyregex property="to" input="@{line}" regexp="(.*):(.*)" select="\2" override="true"/>

            <echo>Copying dir ${from} to ${to} ...</echo>

            <property name="src.dir" value="." /> <property name="dest.dir" value="." />

            <copy todir="${dest.dir}/${to}">     <fileset dir="${src.dir}/${from}">  </fileset> </copy>

     </ac:sequential>

     </ac:for>
```

Comment: Thanks; you may want to mark this as the answer so others may benefit.

Comment: though this works.. I'd call it a hack. @FailedDev whatsay? Can you think of a cleaner solution.

Comment: @PulakAgrawal: well, this is not a hack. This is a in built commmand i used in ANT. The actual text file was a single file. I did split it for my oown convinience. Then I thought of using the original.

Comment: @PulakAgrawal: If you still think it is not useful then I am happy to remove it from the forum. This was the reason I didn't post  the answer before. I did it when you asked me to do so. I am new in ANT. I may have not given the best.

Comment: :) Please don't remove anything. This is a valid answer as it does the job. And this will be useful for many. At least I have kept it in my favorite list. And with my experience I can tell you are in top 10% of ANT developers already so no worries.

If you do not like the word "hack", ok,  but I still maintain its not a clean solution as we are processing from OS, then to a  file (which contains output of LS ??) and then going back to OS to do the copy. 

If I could come up with a cleaner one, I would have answered myself :)

Comment: @PulakAgrawal: Thanks for being generous. Yes, you are right, we are processing from OS then to a file. I had a tight deadline, couldn't spend much time to think and this one worked for me. I am sure, there would be a better solution. Fingers crossed !:)